# Unity object will not return to original position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so I'm trying to make a 2D platforming game in unity, I'm currently trying to make a car on the first level return to it's original position after it reaches a barrier with the tag "Return". Below is the code I have been trying to use to accomplish that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Return : MonoBehaviour
{

Vector3 originalPos;

void Start()
{
    originalPos = new Vector3(75f, -.01f);

}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Return")
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = originalPos;
    }

}
}
```

The code is not doing anything, the car just travels past the barrier I set up. Any information would be helpful, although I would prefer c#. Let it be noted I am still mostly a noob at this, the sites that I learned this much from are: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1359710/i-want-to-reset-my-object-to-its-original-position.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html.

Comment: Do the car and the barrier both have **Colliders**? If your `Return` script is attached to the car, the **Collider** on the car has to have it's _Is Trigger_ property set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hristo commented, you need to make sure that both the car and barrier have colliders attached. As you are using OnTriggerEnter, the car collider (in the inspector) also needs to have the isTrigger box checked (set to true).

I suspect, as your game is 2D, that you may be using 2D colliders and physics (which you should by the way). If this is the case then, you must use `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)` to access a 2D collider and both the car and barrier need 2D colliders (e.g. Box Collider 2D) attached to their game objects. The car again needs the isTrigger box checked (set to true).

ALSO, make sure you have a rigidbody attached to the car (Rigidbody if 3D physics and Rigidbody2D if 2D). Then Body Type to Kinematic in the inspector. This enables the trigger to interact with other colliders, and as it is kinematic it isn't affected by gravity and all.

For 2D colliders and physics, your code would change to this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Return : MonoBehaviour
{

Vector3 originalPos;

void Start()
{
    originalPos = new Vector3(75f, -.01f);

}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Return")
    {
        transform.position = originalPos;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Yes, both objects have colliders and the barrier, and the car's collider has a trigger. The code that Jakey suggested is not helping, here's some screen shots of the inspectors on the car and the barrier.

Car: https://gyazo.com/5868aca369f0a0c88356618a28dc6da3

Barrior: https://gyazo.com/c45f2869374c9f653783bf3c05e68f8a

Comment: Ah, I see your problem (I think). Your “Barrior” object cannot also be a trigger (uncheck isTrigger on barrier). That is because the trigger in Car needs another collider to trigger an event. Not another trigger. Also, you need to attach a Rigidbody2D to the car and set its body type to Kinematic

Comment: Unity won't let me put a rigid body and a polygon collider simultaneously, sorry if this is a simple fix, again I'm a complete noob. What happens: https://gyazo.com/c12a375c023ee0ce6b58b3452b345601

Comment: Did you select Rigidbody2D or just plain old Rigidbody? You need to select Rigidbody2D for 2D physics stuff

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I was being stupid and put a regular rigid body rather than a 2D one, sorry. However now the barrior is destorying the bar instead of sending it back.

Comment: Does that have something to do with your dead scripts? The code you provided will just move the car to (75f, -0.01f). Are they the coordinates you wanted to send it to?

Comment: Another thing, for some reason the car is destroying any garbage cans it drives by also. I don't think my dead script would effect that.
`using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Dead : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        //if the ovject that triggered the event is tagged player
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(2);
            return;
        }
    }
}`
Sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments.

Comment: That dead script loads the level that is in index 2 whenever it's trigger is touched by a collider of an object with the tag "Player". By destroying the car, do you mean it is removed from the heirarchy? Could you send an image of what you mean?

Comment: I was wrong, the barrior isn't destroying the car, the car is destroying the barrior, and any other colliders in its way. Whenever I play the scene the car drives by and destroys any colliders. Also, just to clearify, scene 2 is the game over screen, that's why it load it.

Comment: I don’t see how that can happen with the code you’ve given me. The only way the objects could be destroyed is if you have put some code saying Destroy(...) somewhere. Maybe this tutorial could help you: https://youtu.be/UbPiCgCkHTE

Comment: I have already seen that tutorial, here is almost everything I can send: Full Picture of scene: https://gyazo.com/bcfb9681e9adff77abded6fce13175ec Car Inspector: https://gyazo.com/8af7be1692facf32e177e2a1aa064870 https://gyazo.com/c0c9d71c80d16243780918cfb7ccba63 Barrier Inspector: https://gyazo.com/91482b6899771aa1d596ad47adfd1296 Move Script: https://gyazo.com/eab732de01ccde76d04a40b69a8ac736 Dead Script: https://gyazo.com/4a473be7d98217334851b4a669896e61 Return Script: https://gyazo.com/b394bef41386b6e6f9f7a0993359a0dc
Theres everything that has to do with this.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it, thank you so much for your help, the problem was that the script I was using to get to the next level, for some reason had the ability to destroy things that werent tagged player. So the door destroyed the car whenever it passed it. I still don't completely understand why it did that even after I moved the door out of the way, but its fixed now so I don't really care. Thank you again for being so helpful, it means a lot!

Comment: Ok, that's great you fixed it (sort of)! I don't really understand how that could happen either. I did notice that you had sorting layer "Invisible" on the "barrior" object, so something could be setting it. Maybe the objects are appearing to be destroyed because they have not been set with the sorting layer and order in layer that you want. If all the sprites are in the same layer and order in layer, they can be moved behind one another when they cross each other. No worries. I tumbled along trying to learn with my first game too. The art looks very cool. (Please tick answered if I helped)